# Grunt - Watch new folders

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to get grunt-contrib-watch to watch my images folder, and run grunt-imageoptim on any added/changed jpgs, gifs, or pngs.

My code below runs fine for running imageoptim on new images, as long as I don't make any new folders. Apparently this has been fixed in recent versions but I'm pretty new to Grunt so it might be something basic I'm missing. I've gotten it to see changes / new folders in watch through a less specific wildcard, but then i can't stop imageoptim from running on all images in all the folders.

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    imageoptim: {
      options: {
        jpegMini: false,
        imageAlpha: true,
        quitAfter: true
      },
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['images/**/*.jpg', 'images/**/*.png', 'images/**/*.gif'],
      tasks: ['imageoptim'],
      options: {
        spawn: false,
      },
    },
  });


  // imageoptim
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-imageoptim');
  // grunt watch
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['imageoptim']);

  var changedFiles = Object.create(null);
  var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function() {
    grunt.config('imageoptim.all.src', Object.keys(changedFiles));
    changedFiles = Object.create(null);
  }, 200);
  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
    changedFiles[filepath] = action;
    onChange();
  });
};
```

(the bottom function is to run imageoptim on a watch change, and then prevent it from seeing it's own changes as changes to act on again)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Whoops, answered my own question :P I was previously (before posting the question) setting src in imageoptim instead of changing files in watch. This works:

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    imageoptim: {
      options: {
        jpegMini: false,
        imageAlpha: true,
        quitAfter: true
      },
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['images/**'],
      tasks: ['imageoptim'],
      options: {
        spawn: false,
      },
    },
  });


  // imageoptim
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-imageoptim');
  // grunt watch
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['imageoptim']);

  var changedFiles = Object.create(null);
  var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function() {
    grunt.config('imageoptim.all.src', Object.keys(changedFiles));
    changedFiles = Object.create(null);
  }, 200);
  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
    changedFiles[filepath] = action;
    onChange();
  });
};
```